# Calculating the time and converting into Days, Hours and Minutes

Tags: google-sheets

I have been trying to convert the subtracted time to days, hours and minutes but my formula is missing with some functionality which i am unable to track.

I would appreciate your help.

```
=INT(I4)&" days "&TEXT(I4,"h"" hrs ""m"" mins """)
```

I have attached a Sheet where i have made all these calculation.

[google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aG_7caUyo_fMsqxCCafjIND8RZtSBu3zM2fTMu3A5wI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the result you expect to get?

Comment: Result is available in the Sheet column `K`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this formula that checks if each value is existent and adds its correspondent suffix:

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(dif,IF(D4:D="","",IF(ROUNDDOWN(HOUR(dif)/9)=0,"",ROUNDDOWN(HOUR(dif)/9)&" days ")
&IF(MOD(HOUR(dif),9)=0,"",MOD(HOUR(dif),9)&" hs.")&IF(MINUTE(dif)=0,"",MINUTE(dif)&" mins")))
(E4:E-D4:D+IF(E4:E<D4:D,1,0)))
```

[image: =ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(dif,IF(D4:D="","",IF(ROUNDDOWN(HOUR(dif)/9)=0,"",ROUNDDOWN(HOUR(dif)/9)&" days ") &IF(MOD(HOUR(dif),9)=0,"",MOD(HOUR(dif),9)&" hs.")&IF(MINUTE(dif)=0,"",MINUTE(dif)&" mins"))) (E4:E-D4:D+IF(E4:E<D4:D,1,0)))]

PS: You can change the 9 to a cell that actually contains the value of the shift, in case it can change

Comment: Thank you very much you are genius. Is it possible to use `SUMIFS` function  to sum the individual time instead of this line `(E4:E-D4:D+IF(E4:E<D4:D,1,0))`

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! Of course, just choose your row and remove the ARRAYFORMULA: `=LAMBDA(dif,IF(D4:D="","",IF(ROUNDDOWN(HOUR(dif)/9)=0,"",ROUNDDOWN(HOUR(dif)/9)&" days ")
&IF(MOD(HOUR(dif),9)=0,"",MOD(HOUR(dif),9)&" hs.")&IF(MINUTE(dif)=0,"",MINUTE(dif)&" mins")))
(E4-D4+IF(E4<D4,1,0))`

Comment: thank you very much but i want to use it like this: `=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(dif,IF(K4:K="","",IF(ROUNDDOWN(HOUR(dif)/9)=0,"",ROUNDDOWN(HOUR(dif)/9)&"d ")
&IF(MOD(HOUR(dif),9)=0,"",MOD(HOUR(dif),9)&"h ")&IF(MINUTE(dif)=0,"",MINUTE(dif)&"m")))
(SUMIFS(I:I,B:B,K:K)))` want to sum the Column `I` from sheet. based on `user id`

Comment: Oh, you need a summary per user? That's another scenario! I suggest you publish a new question with the expected result and what you've tried. If you want, post the link of the new question here in the comments and me or any other will happily help!

Comment: I have posted a new question can you please go through it @Martín [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75755470/replacing-the-time-and-converting-into-days-hours-and-minutes)